# Shopify Liquid - Unable to manipluate string inside section

Tags: shopify, jekyll, liquid

So I have some data which is a string (but I'm going to split out later into an array), I'm passing it into a section with the following method:

```
{%- liquid
    assign myData = 'data],[data],[data'

    capture header
        section 'header'
    endcapture

    assign header = header | replace: '%%DATA%%', myData
-%}
```

Then within `sections/header.liquid` I have the following

```
{% capture replaced_data %}
%%DATA%%
{% endcapture %}

{%- liquid
    assign data = replaced_data | split: '],['

    echo data[0]
-%}
```

Now based off that, you'd expect the first `data` to be printed out, but infact the following is printed out

```
data],[data],[data
```

For some reason I'm no longer able to do any manipulation with this data once its in the `sections/header.liquid` file. I've even tried doing a replace on the `],[` but it just doesn't take effect. Any ideas on this?

For the main file `theme.liquid` which holds it all. My original data comes from the `section 'categories.liquid`, then passes through a snippet which just does some tidying up of the data and then I replaced the `%%DATA%%` with it in the header which I also captured.

```
{%- liquid
    capture categories
      section 'categories'
    endcapture

    capture header
      section 'header'
    endcapture

    capture category_data
      render 'category-data', data: categories, type: 'all'
    endcapture

    echo header | replace: '%%DATA%%', category_data
-%}
```

After some further testing, it seems I'm able to add data to the string and remove it, but unable to remove any of the original data, like this example:

```
assign data = replaced_data | append: '],[' | remove: '],['
```

This adds `],[` on the end and succesfully removes it, but it does not remove the `],[` in the rest of the string. Its almost like the replaced_data string is read only

Comment: how you call the files? where you call render/include/section ?

Comment: Just updated the original post with that info

Answer (score 1):

header output `%%DATA%%` since `assign data = replaced_data | split: '],['` return an array of 0;

if `assign myData = 'data],[data],[data'`  and `assign header = header | replace: '%%DATA%%', myData` 
header output `data],[data],[data`, which is expected.

to fix,

```
{%- liquid
capture categories
  section 'categories'
endcapture

capture header
  section 'header'
endcapture

capture category_data
  render 'category-data', data: categories, type: 'all'
endcapture

 assign replacedHeader = header | replace: '%%DATA%%', 'data],[data],[data'
 assign headerArray = replaceHeader | split: "],[" 
-%}
```